# Refactoring WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, api, api-design

I had to recently add a new feature to to an existing application I wrote and looking at this section of code realized it might be time to refactor and improve.

Original Index Method:

- IsUserEnrolled **<-- WCF Call**

  - If Not enrolled

    - Run Rules if the user can enroll  **<-- WCF Call**

      - If user is not valid redirect to No Access
      - If user is valid to enroll redirect to register
  - If User is enrolled

    - Get items **<-- WCF Call**
    - Show Index page

Three wcf calls to the backend web service

With the new addition I needed some new information, some user options.

- IsUserEnrolled **<-- WCF Call**

  - If Not enrolled

    - Run Rules if the user can enroll **<-- WCF Call**

      - If user is not valid redirect to No Access
      - If user is valid to enroll redirect to register
  - If User is enrolled

    - Get items **<-- WCF Call**
    - Get user options **<-- WCF Call**
    - Show Index page

This feature resulted in a new WCF Call which made this one method have 4 calls over the wire.  There has to be a better way.

My proposal was to wrap this into one wcf call to gather all the information about the user, are they enrolled, items, run rules if needed, and user options.

- Get User Information (result object for short) **<--WCF Call**

  - If not result.IsEnrolled

    - If the result.RulesResult.UserIsValid property is false

      - Redirect to No Access
    - If that property is true

      - Redirect to register
  - If result.IsEnrolled

    - Populate the ViewModel with result.UserOptions and result.Items

**We only have one call that is good, however my questions**

- Does having one object make sense as a result?
- If IsEnrolled is true the RulesResult will be null, does having a null property make sense in this instance?  Maybe supply a result that also says the user is enrolled incase it is ever inspected later on?
- If IsEnrolled is false, RulesResult will be populated (makes sense) however Items will be null (sort of makes sense) user options will also be null
  In this case does having an empty list for items and user options make more sense then null?
- From an api design point of view does the second option make sense or is the result to closely related to the UI?

Code example for both verions:
**Version 1:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    using (var client =ServiceFactory.CreateChannel())
    {
        var isMemberEnrolled = client.IsMemberEnrolled(User.Identity.Name);

        if (!isMemberEnrolled)
        {
            var accessResult = client.RunRules(User.Identity.Name);

            if (!accessResult.UserIsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("NoAccess");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Register");
        }

        var userOptions = client.GetUserOptions(User.Identity.Name);

        List<Item> items = client.GetUserItems(User.Identity.Name);

        var viewModel = new ViewModel(userOptions, items);

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

**Version 2 (Refactor):**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    using (var client = ServiceFactory.CreateChannel())
    {
        var userInformation = client.GetUserInformation(User.Identity.Name);

        if (!userInformation.IsMemberEnrolled)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(!userInformation.RulesResult.UserIsValid ? "NoAccess" : "Register");
        }

        var viewModel = new ViewModel(userInformation.UserOptions, userInformation.Items);

        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for API efficiency, option #2 would definitely perform better.

As far as having unused parameters all in one result object, this could easily be solved with an abstract result class, then dividing the two different responses into two different concrete sub types.

```
  [KnownType( typeof( UserInfoEnrolledResult ) )]
  [KnownType( typeof( UserInfoNotEnrolledResult ) )]
  [DataContract]
  public abstract class UserInfoResult
  {
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class UserInfoEnrolledResult : UserInfoResult
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string UserOptions { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string[] Items { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  class UserInfoNotEnrolledResult : UserInfoResult
  {
    [DataMember]
    public bool UserIsValid { get; set; }
  }
```

Then your client code would become something like...

```
  using ( var client = ServiceFactory.CreateChannel() )
  {
    var userInformation = client.GetUserInformation( User.Identity.Name );

    if ( userInformation is UserInfoNotEnrolledResult )
    {
      return RedirectToAction( ((UserInfoNotEnrolledResult)userInformation).UserIsValid ? "NoAccess" : "Register" );
    }

    var enrolledUserInformation = (UserInfoEnrolledResult)userInformation;

    var viewModel = new ViewModel( enrolledUserInformation.UserOptions, enrolledUserInformation.Items );

    return View( viewModel );
  }
```

This makes it clear to the client that two different responses are possible, and keeps it clear which parameters are used or needed for what kind of response.

I think this is a perfectly fine way to go.  If you start to run across cases when you find yourself creating many different kinds of functions which are all roughly similar steps with slight differences like...

```
UserInfoResult GetUserInformation( string name );
UserInfoResult GetUserInformationWithoutRuleCheck( string name );
UserInfoResult GetUserInformationWithDoubleSecretChecks( string name );
```

then, it might be worth it to break these larger functions down into multiple WCF calls to ensure you don't have an explosion of API methods.

Comment: I do like the idea of the abstract result, it is very clear to the caller that different results are possible.